# Log4j Logger NullPointerException in Beans when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging

We have a Spring MVC application running on multiple Tomcat 7 servers on RackSpace. In each class we have something akin to the following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
protected final transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

We get all of the logging entries for our MVC controllers, and most of the logging from withing our model classes (JavaBeans), but occasionally the following call:

```
logger.debug("some logging");
```

Throws a NullPointerException. Apparently "logger" is null, but I have no explanation why it would be. It is initialized at the top of the class declaration, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, are you sure the Instances of the class you are logging with is never serialized / deserialized? That would cause your logger to get lost.

And, if that's the case, why not declare the logger as `static`? Here's some info from slf4j.org that can help you decide the proper approach:

http://slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static

If you declare them as static, once they work you could trust that they will always do (as long as your JVM is working).

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try with replacing the `transient` with `static` for one.

Then don't use the `this.getClass()` but `THE_ACTUAL_CLASS.class` as argument for the getLogger() method